# How to find the original matrix when its adjoint is given only?

Tags: matrices

With the adjoint matrix of the $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ given by
$$\operatorname{adj} A= \left[\matrix{1& 3 &-4\\-2& 2& -2\\1& -3& 4}\right]$$
how do I find $A$?

Comment: which formula should i be using? A.adj A= I???

Comment: I made your matrix a bit more readable. Please check that I didn't do any mistakes.

Comment: no mistakes but how i'm going to solve this?

Comment: $A\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A)I$ doesn't seem like a bad place to start. There are nine unknown elements of $A$, and this gives you nine equations.

Comment: no its not coming

Comment: Am I wrong, or isn't the adjoint of the adjoint the original matrix?

Comment: i tried by taking the adjoint of the given matrix but the answer is not coming.

Comment: @MPW Only for $n=2$. Generally times $(\det A)^{n-2}$.

Comment: nothing is given except the adjoint of the original matrix.I still cannot figure out how to approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outline:

From your given matrix $\operatorname{adj} A$, you find that $\det(\operatorname{adj} A)=4$.

You also have $A\cdot\operatorname{adj}A=(\det A)I$.  (Standard equation).

From this, and the fact that your matrices are $3\times 3$, you get $4\cdot (\det A)=(\det A)^3$.

So $\det A = \pm 2$  (Certainly $\det A\ne 0$, or else $\operatorname{adj} A$ would be singular.

Now go back to $A\cdot\operatorname{adj}A=(\det A)I$, and using the known information, find $A$.  (There are two possibilities.)

Comment: A.[2 -1 1][-1 1 -1][1 -1 3]3x3=[4 0 0][0 4 0][0 0 4]3x3.

Comment: I got something different.  I used $A=(\det A)\cdot I\cdot (\operatorname{adj}A)^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If you can use the following two (not commonly known) formulas, the calculations are easy:

1. $\det(\operatorname{adj}(A))=\det A^{n-1}$
2. $\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A))=\det A^{n-2}\cdot A$

Comment: how will I obtain the determinant then?

Comment: adj(adj A)= [2 0 2][6 0 6][4 6 8]3x3.I hope so...

Comment: @SwetaGhosh The main question is: what tools can you use? If it is a standard linear algebra course, you rather don't know these equalities. On the other hand, you can solve 9 equations to find the coefficients, but it is rather time-consuming. Hence any additional information should be helpful.

Comment: det(adjA) did the job much easier.